Please tell me how to implement the Fibonacci sequence recursive method in Risk-5 assembly language
if (n == 0) return 0;

else if (n == 1) return 1;

return fibonacci(n-2) +

fibonacci(n-1);

I use RARS1_6 Converting the above function into assembly language requires that the input be received as X30 and the output of the function as X31. I really don't know, so I'm curious if anyone knows.ㅜㅜㅜㅜㅜㅜㅜㅜ
The stack implementation is not working well.ㅜㅜ

Function calling, on a machine that uses register conventions such as for parameter passing, call-preserved and call-clobbered resisters is one of the most complicated things in assembly.  We cannot answer the question of how to do it without immense detail, so best if you ask a question about where you're stuck, or why, or what concepts you need to understand.

Otherwise, just write the code as needed.  Recursive calls require nothing different from the calling convention, so pretend this function is calling fib2 instead of itself, and the code will look the same.

C compilers can make examples for you, e.g. using -O1 or -Og to avoid optimizing one of the recursive calls into a loop.  https://godbolt.org/ has C compilers for RISC-V.  A recursive calls is just like any function-call from a non-leaf function; nothing is special because of being a call into the same function.  (Unless you're optimizing away part of the calling convention, which you shouldn't be.)

Anyway, closed as a duplicate of an existing recursive Fibonacci Q&A that has a working example.  Since this doesn't seem to be a debugging question asking for help with what's wrong with your code, just a request for a working example.
